# Android Gridview select one item from first page should show same grid item in another page grid

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gridview, android-viewpager

I am working in a task where I am using viewpager and displaying two pages in my layout which draws under a scrollview. Also I am able to draw required contents in my gridview and all items are properly placed.

Now I have to add functionality where if I select one gridview1 item then in another page2 empty gridview2, that item should be added and displayed as added item from gridview1 of page 1.

Please suggest some options.

Comment: Write a method in gridview2's adapter that adds items to the list & call this method from onItemClick/ onClick of gridview1's adapter.

Comment: @Codetoconnect please elaborate the problem even more by giving code snippets and graphical interpretation.